# Unable to view SVG on live site in browser

Tags: css, svg

I'm having problems getting SVGs to display correctly on my website, http://www.byfrequency.co.uk. Instead the site displays the fallback PNG's instead.

When I preview the site locally, they display fine in all browsers which leads me to believe there might be some kind of issue server side. Trouble is, I have no idea where to begin to rectify this!

(My web server is Windows 2008 and currently configured for PHP 5.2, ASP, SSI, Perl, ASP.NET 3.5, CGI)

Other things I've investigated is to inspect the object (logo.svg) within Chrome. All this gives me is a message saying "Failed to load response" and is highlighted in red. I've tried putting the files on the local root to see if that would make a difference which is doesn't. And finally, I've looked up numerous articles about displaying SVGs but to no avail.

On a semi-related note, my web fonts also seem to fail to load when the site is inspected but render correctly in Chrome/Safari but not Firefox. Again, the path to these files are correct but I can't seem to be able to rectify this error.

Any thoughts and ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: http://www.byfrequency.co.uk/images/vectors/logo.svg returns 404 not found.

Comment: That's the strange thing - the file path seems to be all correct and also displays correctly when viewed on my local machine...

Comment: File permission problem maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this now with the addition of MIME types within a web.config file.